# React-mde WYSIWYG Editor Absolute Links

Tags: javascript, reactjs, markdown, wysiwyg

Is there any way to begin urls in React-mde with `https://` by default? Absolute links seem to work every time while relative links only work when they begin with `/`, which seems like it would be more confusing for users.

Ex:

Clicking the button to add a new link should show

```
[](https://)
```

instead of

```
[](url)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a solution, but I came up with a good workaround. Since this is React.js and I already have a `handleTextarea(text)` that runs `onChange={this.handleTextarea}` I just added a

```
text = text.replace('](url)', '](https://'.concat(window.location.hostname, '/)'));
```

at the beginning of the `handleTextarea(text)`.